# i want to know what this *list pointer is about in this code

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list, swap, singly-linked-list

this code is about swapping two nodes of the singly linked list.
the *list  variable is in just these two functions not even the main function . I haven't defined what *list pointer variable is but this code still works. why does this works, why we pass *list parameter to these functions when this *list variable is nowhere else except these two function and what value list pointer gets and why please explain.

'''

```
int main()
{
    int n, pos1, pos2;

    // Input node count to create
    printf("Enter number of node to create: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    createList(n);

    // Display list
    printf("\n\nData in list before swapping: \n");
    displayList();

    printf("\nEnter first node position to swap: ");
    scanf("%d", &pos1);
    printf("\nEnter second node position to swap: ");
    scanf("%d", &pos2);

    if (swap(head, pos1, pos2) == 1)
    {
        printf("\nData swapped successfully.\n");
        printf("Data in list after swapping %d node with %d: \n", pos1, pos2);
        displayList();
    }
    else 
    {
        printf("Invalid position, please enter position greater than 0 and less than nodes in list.\n");
    }

    return 0;
}

/**
 * Counts total number of nodes in a linked list.
 * @param *list Pointer to head node of linked list.
 * @returns Total count of nodes in list.
 */
int count(struct node *list)
{
    int nodes = 0;

    while (list != NULL) 
    {
        nodes++;
        list = list->next;
    }

    return nodes;
}

int swap(struct node *list, int pos1, int pos2){
    struct node *node1, *node2, *prev1, *prev2, *temp;
    int i;
    
    //get the far postion among both
    const int maxpos = (pos1 > pos2) ? pos1 : pos2;
    
    //get total in the list
    const int totalnodes = count(list);
    
    //validate swap positions
    if((pos1 <= 0 || pos1 > totalnodes) || (pos2 <= 0 || pos2 > totalnodes)){
        return -1;
    }
    
    //if both position are same then no swapping required
    if(pos1 == pos2){
        return 1;
    }
    
    //identify both nodes to swap 
    i = 1;
    
    temp = list;
}
```

'''

Comment: Can you share how `count` and `swap` are being called from the main function?

Comment: sure Im gonna edit this and show you the main function

Answer (score 0):

The name of the variables being passed can be different in the `main()` and the function being called. Here is a simple example.

```
int foo(int a , int b)
{
return a+b;
}

int main()
{
int c=5,RandomVar=6,sum;
sum = foo(c,RandomVar);
printf("%d",sum);
return 0;
}
```

In the above case, when `foo()` is called, `a` will equal to `c` and `b` will equal to `RnadonVar`.

Now in your case, `*list` is a pointer which is being used to pass the whole link 'list' to the function which is being identified by `head` of the link list.
You traverse a link list using `head`. So such that the 'swap()`function can traverse link list , it is having the`*list`being passed to it which is the`head` of the list in your case.

Answer (score 0):

this function:

```
int swap(struct node *list, int pos1, int pos2){
```

claims that it returns an `int`.   However, that function contains a execution path that runs off the end of the function, without returning anything

regarding

```
struct node *node1, *node2, *prev1, *prev2, *temp;
```

The only variable that is used in the above line is: `*temp` Suggest replacing that line with;

```
struct node *temp;
```

however, this variable is only set but not used.

regarding;

```
int i;
```

This `i` variable is set but never used.

regarding;

```
const int maxpos = (pos1 > pos2) ? pos1 : pos2;
```

The const `maxpos` is never used.  Suggest elimination of this line

the `struct node` is not defined anywhere in the posted code

Answer (score 0):

The names of the variables in a function are only scoped to the function itself. So the variable `*list` is only called that within the function itself. But when you call the `swap` function, you are passing a memory reference, which is only called `*list` within the function itself.